# How to handle xml missing ns in Java SOAP WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a `Java` `SOAP` web service that works as follows: I'm receiving messages from 2 clients. The difference between them two is in the body of a specific field where there is a `ns` tag. I have implemented the web service using `wsimport` from a `WSDL`.

Client 1:

```
<soapenv:Envelope...>
...
    <ns9:StackOverFlow xmlns:ns9="...example...">
        ...
    </ns9:StackOverFlow>
... 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Client 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope...>
...
    <StackOverFlow xmlns="...example...">
        ...
    </StackOverFlow>
... 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`client1` works fine, but in `client2` there is a field, StackOverFlow for example, that always converts to null in my `Java` web service. After debugging and looking into it, I have figured out it is because the missing `ns`.

Is there a way to support those 2 clients without asking them to change the `xml` they are sending me?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the `StackOverflow` element is in the `...example...` namespace, and no conformant software will handle the two cases differently.

However, be aware that a difference arises in that default namespaces are adopted by child elements while prefixed namespaces are not.